# Concatenate the columns if there is a match in the same file perl/awk

Tags: perl, awk

I have a file as following:
file1.txt

```
1 101 111  BCX A@WWW  123
1 298 306  CCC A@QQQ  234
1 299 308  CCD A@QQQ  
1 299 309  DDD A@ZZZ  345
1 299 309  DDD A@ZZZ  678
```

I am trying to merge the 6th column, if the 5th column is the same.
The output should be:

```
1 101 111  BCX A@WWW  123
1 298 306  CCC A@QQQ  234
1 299 308  CCD A@QQQ  234
1 299 309  DDD A@ZZZ  345,678
1 299 309  DDD A@ZZZ  345,678
```

So if 5th column is the same, the 6th column should be the same.

What I am trying makes me lose data as it doesn't keep the line if 6th column is empty:

```
perl -lane 'if($.==1){@a=@F;next} if($F[4]eq$a[4]){$a[5].=";$F[5]";}else{for($i=0;$i<@a;$i++){printf "\t%s",$a[$i]};print"";@a=@F}
            END{for($i=0;$i<@a;$i++){printf "\t%s",$a[$i]};print""}' file1.txt 
    1   101 111 BCX A@WWW   123
    1   298 306 CCC A@QQQ   234;
    1   299 309 DDD A@ZZZ   345;678
```

How can I keep all lines?

Comment: Are the related records always next to each other in the input file, or could line 10 contain `1 299 309  DDD A@XXX  345` and line 20 contain `1 299 309  DDD A@XXX  678` while data lines starting with `2` (so they don't match either line 10 or 20) could appear on lines 11-19?  It's a lot easier to deal with if the related lines are adjacent, but that could be a fluke of the example data.  Also, will you ever get more than two records in a row matching?  Could you have a required output line like `1 299 309  DDD A@ZZZ  345,678,901,234`?

Comment: Yes I do. It can get to 7-8 records

Comment: And if you get 7-8 records in a row, will they all be together in the input?  I note that you have two different sets of values in columns 1-4 with the same value `A@QQQ` in column 5, and they get treated together (both end up with the concatenated values from column 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
       if($6!="")
       a[$5]=($5 in a ? a[$5] ",":"")$6;
       next
     }
     {
       $6=a[$5]
     }1' infile infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat f
1 101 111  BCX A@WWW  123
1 298 306  CCC A@QQQ  234
1 299 308  CCD A@QQQ  
1 299 309  DDD A@ZZZ  345
1 299 309  DDD A@ZZZ  678

$ awk 'FNR==NR{if($6!="")a[$5]=($5 in a ? a[$5] ",":"")$6;next}{$6=a[$5]}1' f f
1 101 111 BCX A@WWW 123
1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234
1 299 308 CCD A@QQQ 234
1 299 309 DDD A@ZZZ 345,678
1 299 309 DDD A@ZZZ 345,678
```

Comment: Two passes over the data file works provided you have a data file.  It means you can't take the input direct from a pipe, though — or a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`, without changing the input spacing

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$5]=$5 in a?a[$5] ($6==""?"":","$6):$0; next} 
               {print a[$5]}' file{,}

1 101 111  BCX A@WWW  123
1 298 306  CCC A@QQQ  234
1 298 306  CCC A@QQQ  234
1 299 309  DDD A@ZZZ  345,678
1 299 309  DDD A@ZZZ  345,678
```

Comment: This code loses the first 4 columns. They are different but it duplicates it

Comment: This is what was asked *"I am trying to merge the 6th column, if the 5th column is the same."*

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$5]=a[$5] && $NF~/[0-9]+/?a[$5]","$NF:($NF~/[0-9]+/?$NF:a[$5]);next} {$NF=$5 in a?$NF!~/[0-9]+/?$5 FS a[$5]:a[$5]:$5;} 1'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now. Will add explanation soon too here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$5]=a[$5] && $NF~/[0-9]+/?a[$5]","$NF:($NF~/[0-9]+/?$NF:a[$5]);
  next
}
{
  $NF=$5 in a?$NF!~/[0-9]+/?$5 FS a[$5]:a[$5]:$5;
}
1
'   Input_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 101 111 BCX A@WWW 123
1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234
1 299 308 CCD A@QQQ 234
1 299 309 DDD A@ZZZ 345,678
1 299 309 DDD A@ZZZ 345,678
```

Comment: Two passes over the data file works provided you have a data file.  It means you can't take the input direct from a pipe, though — or a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It's tagged perl, so I feel we need a perl answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#read all the rows from STDIN or specified file into an array of arrays. 
my @rows = map { [split] } <>; 

#define a hash to look for lines with matching keys. 
my %value_lookup;
#iterate the rows.
foreach my $row ( @rows ) {
   #check if there's a '6th field' (one of the examples is blank)
   if ( $row -> [5] ) { 
     #push it into a lookup list if there is one. (might only be one element for non dupes. 
     push ( @{$value_lookup{$row -> [4]}}, $row -> [5]);
  }
}

#iterate each row, replacing the 6th element (index 5)
#with whatever is in the value lookup above. 
#or blank, if relevant. 
foreach my $row ( @rows ) {
   $row -> [5] = join ( ",", @{$value_lookup{$row->[4]}});
   #print output, tab separated. 
   print join ("\t", @$row ),"\n";
}
```

This is a more exhaustive solution, as it'll work with any line ordering. If you can rely on it just being consecutive lines being merged, it simplifies somewhat.

With your input, this gives:

```
1   101 111 BCX A@WWW   123
1   298 306 CCC A@QQQ   234
1   299 308 CCD A@QQQ   234
1   299 309 DDD A@ZZZ   345,678
1   299 309 DDD A@ZZZ   345,678
```